# Dependence of the parameter while using the Teorema de Lax–Milgram for solving a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations, linear-pde, elliptic-operators

In the Book Evans, Partial Differential Equations, 2010, Theorem 3, p. 319, we have that there's an $\gamma \geq 0$ such that for each $\mu \geq \gamma$ and each function $f \in L^2(\Omega)$, there's a unique weak solution in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ of the equatin
$$
(P) 
\begin{cases}
L(u) + \mu u = f, \Omega \\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,u = 0, \partial \Omega.
\end{cases}
$$
Essentially, we the the $\gamma$ for which the associated bilinear form is coercive.

I'm wondering if the solution depends on the $\mu$ I take, that is, given $\mu_1, \mu_2 \geq \gamma$ and $u_1,u_2$ the respective weak solutions of $(P)$, we have $u_1 = u_2$?

Comment: Of course, the solution depends on $\mu$. One can show that $u\to0$ for $\mu\to+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you, daw.